# How to insert one ndarray to another ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

These are two ndarray.

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

B=[[31,42,53],[11,17,29],[100,59,32]]
```

How to make a new ndarray 'C' by merge two ndarray A and B?

```
C=[[1,2,3],[31,42,53],[4,5,6], [11,17,29],[7,8,9],[100,59,32]]
```

Comment: is this C++? i see numpy so python?  can you add the tag for which language this is in

Answer (score 2):

Using `array-initialization` to achieve that interweaving task -

```
def interweave(a, b):
    N = a.shape[1]
    M = a.shape[0] + b.shape[0]
    out_dtype = np.result_type(a.dtype, b.dtype)
    out = np.empty((M,N),dtype=out_dtype)
    out[::2] = a
    out[1::2] = b
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [274]: A
Out[274]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [275]: B
Out[275]: 
array([[ 31,  42,  53],
       [ 11,  17,  29],
       [100,  59,  32]])

In [276]: interweave(A, B)
Out[276]: 
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 31,  42,  53],
       [  4,   5,   6],
       [ 11,  17,  29],
       [  7,   8,   9],
       [100,  59,  32]])
```

If `A` and `B` are of same shapes, we can also stack and reshape -

```
In [283]: np.hstack((A,B)).reshape(-1,A.shape[1])
Out[283]: 
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 31,  42,  53],
       [  4,   5,   6],
       [ 11,  17,  29],
       [  7,   8,   9],
       [100,  59,  32]])
```

Or `np.stack((A,B),axis=1).reshape(-1,A.shape[1])`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use numpy library. like this:

```
import numpy as np
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B=[[31,42,53],[11,17,29],[100,59,32]]
C= np.concatenate((A, B), axis=0)
```

more information about concatenate with numpy in this link :
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html