# concatenate two arrays in python with alternating the columns in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

How to concatenate two arrays in numpy python by taking first column from the first array and fisrt column from the second, then second column from first and second from the other, etc..? that is if I have `A=[a1 a2 a3]` and `B=[b1 b2 b3]`
I want the resulting array to be `[a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3]`

Comment: That's obviously not concatenation, but zipping.

Comment: @Olaf Well the term concatenate is more popular among than zipping when dealing with NumPy arrays. To be more correct about the terminology, it would be interleaving.

Comment: It's a shame really if this is considered as "too broad", going by the close votes.

Comment: @Divakar: I used the term "zip-ping" intentionally, because that's a Python standard function which should work on NumPy arrays, too. And for the CVs: OP does not show any code, does not say if there are constraints which e.g. disallow using `zip`. A shame it got three upvotes actually. It does not show any research effort and why the standard way is not used.

Comment: @Olaf What's the "standard way" again? `zip(A,B)`? Any other way of zipping would result in a list/tuple output anyway. That won't give an array output and OP has mentioned that they want an array output. The overhead of converting any zipping based list result to an array isn't a good idea on performance. That's why zipping isn't too popular in NumPy territory.

Comment: @Divakar "The overhead of converting any zipping based list result to an array isn't a good idea on performance" - I don't see any mention of performance in the question. Looks like one reason for too broad CVs.

Comment: @Olaf Well then NumPy developers won't be wasting there effort on developing functions on [`joining arrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays) if `zipping` is the "standard way" both in Python world and NumPy world. I guess we would never know what's the "standard way", because it's not officially declared anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Few approaches with stacking could be suggested -

```
np.vstack((A,B)).ravel('F')
np.stack((A,B)).ravel('F')
np.ravel([A,B],'F')
```

Sample run -

```
In [291]: A
Out[291]: array([3, 5, 6])

In [292]: B
Out[292]: array([13, 15, 16])

In [293]: np.vstack((A,B)).ravel('F')
Out[293]: array([ 3, 13,  5, 15,  6, 16])

In [294]: np.ravel([A,B],'F')
Out[294]: array([ 3, 13,  5, 15,  6, 16])
```

Comment: Does this work if the columns are vectors and not scalars ?

Comment: @Sunreef Not sure what you mean by - `columns are vectors`. We don't really have a "vector" definition in NumPy. What we have are 1D, 2D,  arrays etc. Do you mean if the inputs are 2D arrays?

Comment: Yes, if A and B are 2D arrays, will your solution provide a 2D array with interleaved columns ? Because I think `ravel` outputs a 1D array no matter what the input shape is like.

Comment: @Sunreef Solution here is for 1D arrays only. For 2D, depends along which axis you would want that interleaving. Here's for along the rows - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030728/. Should need minor tweaks for interleaving along cols.

Comment: For 2d arrays, try `np.stack((A,B),2).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)`

Comment: @hpaulj Yup for interleaving along cols.

Answer (score 3):

If we have 2d arrays then we can do the follwoing

```
A = np.zeros((5,2))
B = np.ones((5,2))
row_a, col_a = np.shape(A)
row_b, col_b = np.shape(B)
```

Mix columns in alternating fashion

```
assert row_a == row_b, 'number of rows should be same'
np.ravel([A,B],order="F").reshape(row_a,col_a+col_b)
```

This will give

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

To mix rows

```
assert col_a == col_b, 'number of cols should be same'
np.ravel([A,B],order="F").reshape(col_a,row_a+row_b).T
```

Which will give

```
array([[0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

With `numpy.dstack()` and `numpy.flatten()` routines:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
result = np.dstack((a,b)).flatten()

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[1 4 2 5 3 6]
```